# Use like in T-SQl to search for words separated by an unknown number of spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this query:

select * from table where column like '%firstword[something]secondword[something]thirdword%'

What do I replace [something] with to match an unknown number of spaces?

Edited to add: % will not work as it matches any character, not just spaces.

Comment: Just to be clear, searching for "The Quick Brown Fox", you would want to find "The_Quick___Brown_Fox" but not "The_Quickest_Brown_Fox"?  (Sorry for the underscores, SO doesn't seem to like extra spaces)

Comment: that is correct. I know the words exactly, but depending on what system and or what user entered the text, there could be any number of spaces between each word.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps somewhat optimistically assuming "unknown number" includes zero.

```
select * 
from table where 
REPLACE(column_name,' ','') like '%firstwordsecondwordthirdword%'
```

Comment: I think this is what I need. I have no problem with unknown including zero.

Comment: This seems to work as needed. Thanks! I made this the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following may help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx
as it describes using regular expressions in SQL queries in SQL Server 2005

Comment: I found that (or a similar) article earlier. Every article I found only helped me with a known number of spaces, I am looking for unknown. Maybe it is impossible in T-SQL. Wouldn't be the first thing.

Comment: @Sean - Regular expression syntax would definitely allow this. +1. But you need to enable CLR and install an assembly that shells the .NET framework Regex object.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest cleaning the input data instead, but this example may work when you call it as a function from the `SELECT` statement. Note that this will potentially be **very** expensive.

http://www.bigresource.com/MS_SQL-Replacing-multiple-spaces-with-a-single-space-9llmmF81.html